# PHP query inside while loop fails

Tags: php, mysqli

```
    $id = 2;
    // query to fetch delayed
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM leads WHERE status = ('$id') LIMIT 1";
    $obResult = $objConnection->query($sql);
    // query to fetch if there is no delayed
    $q = "SELECT * FROM leads WHERE status = ('$id') AND later != '1' ORDER BY postnummer LIMIT 1";
    $oResult = $objConnection->query($q);
    // primary query to run, which makes use of the two above accordingly
    $query = "SELECT * FROM leads WHERE status = ('$id') LIMIT 1";
    $objResult = $objConnection->query($query);

    while ($row = $objResult->fetch_object()) {
        if (new DateTime() > $row->delay && $row->delay != '0000-00-00 00:00:00') {
            while ($row = $obResult->fetch_object()) {
                echo $row->firmanavn;
            }
        } else {
            while ($row = $oResult->fetch_object()) {
                echo $row->firmanavn;
            }
        }
    }
```

Changed my code to this, and still i got the same problem, the if clause if met, but it echoes from my else instead

Comment: if `$id is given earlier` why do query inside a loop?

Comment: I need this part in the second query: ORDER BY postnummer LIMIT 1

Comment: @user he's saying you can make that query outside of the loop and save yourself some resources.

Comment: Learn how to use SQL JOINs, and then you won't need to execute queries inefficiently inside a PHP loop

Comment: Is it even possible to join the same table into itself?

Comment: It's perfectly possible to join a table to itself, use aliases

Answer (score 2):

Reason is that you are using same variable names that overwrite each other. `$objResult` rename this to something like `$objResult2` for the inner query.

One thing to keep in mind is that your inner query inside a loop is really unnecessary unless you did not provide some piece of code. You can just put that query outside of `while loop`. Will save you time & memory.

Comment: Id did that now, still if fails

Answer (score 0):

Although I think there are other ways this code could be cleaned up, it seems to me that you're attempting to compare a DateTime object to a date string, which is going to yield unpredictable results. Try changing your while part to:

```
$current_date = new DateTime();

while ($row = $objResult->fetch_object()) {
    if (
        $current_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') > $row->delay &&
        $row->delay != '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
    ) {
        while ($row = $obResult->fetch_object()) {
            echo $row->firmanavn;
        }
    } else {
        while ($row = $oResult->fetch_object()) {
            echo $row->firmanavn;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure this will fully solve your issues, but it should get you closer.